# How to pass multiple statements dynamically in MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a stored procedure in MySQL 5.7.33 where I have to execute that statement to update the values in the table.

Sample data table:

```
ID COL Parent
1A 20   NULL
2B 30   NULL
3C 40   NULL
```

I have two statements which I'm sending dynamically in stored procedure. The first statement works fine. I'm able to group concat like below:

```
update Test.SAMPLE SET COL = 0 where ID IN ('1A','2B','3C');
```

Whereas coming to second statement, parent value also needs to update. So, I'm looking to get a statement like below:

```
update Test.SAMPLE set COL =0,parent='1A' where ID ='1A';
update Test.SAMPLE set COL =0,parent='2B' where ID ='2B';
update Test.SAMPLE set COL =0,parent='3C' where ID ='3C';
```

Sample procedure :

```
    DELIMITER ;;
    
    CREATE PROCEDURE update_stmt ()  
    BEGIN  
    SELECT concat('update Test.SAMPLE SET COL = 0 where ID IN (',
                  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('''', ID, '''')),');')
    FROM Test.SAMPLE 
    UNION ALL
    select  concat('update Test.SAMPLE set COL=0,PARENT = '''', E.ID, '''' where ID IN (',
                  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('''', ID, '''')),');') as statement  from 
   Test.SAMPLE 
   JOIN (SELECT  ID,COL FROM Test.SAMPLE )E 
   ON E.COL = S.COL;
    INTO @sql; 
    PREPARE stmt from @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END;;
    DELIMITER ;
```

I'm not able to append the second statement dynamically in the procedure.

Comment: There is no volume or ticket column in the sample data.

Comment: @P.Salmon I have updated the question now please have a look

Comment: ??doesn't this all boil down to update Test.SAMPLE set COL =0,parent=id; or is there something else going on that you have chosen to go down this route?

Comment: @P.Salmon I Have given that for understanding purpose in real time I have different set of queries .I'm only focusing on how to execute Mutiple update  statements . Please don't  care about  Update logic

Comment: The answer given is correct, since you can only submit one statement at a time then generate and execute them in a loop

Comment: @P.Salmon can you suggest on how to run the loop for these select statements

Comment: Are you familiar with cursors? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249479/discussion-between-mohan111-and-p-salmon).

Answer (score 0):

You must prepare and execute each statement separately.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/prepare.html says:

> The text must represent a single statement, not multiple statements.

The same limitation exists at the MySQL API level:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html

> The multiple statement and result capabilities can be used only with mysql_real_query() or mysql_query(). They cannot be used with the prepared statement interface. Prepared statement handlers are defined to work only with strings that contain a single statement.

Comment: I have gone through this but not able to implement it. Can you suggest any other alternate